# Do I need to put await before every statement in an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I have an async function where some things seem to execute before other things out of order. I think it is because I'm using an async function. But how can I make it execute in the correct order (the way it is written?). Do I need to put `await` before every statement like this?

Or is my syntax not correct?

```
async foodDelivered(order_id, table_id)
{
    await let tmp_order_id = order_id
    await let deliveryTime = 0

    await this.btnDeliveredLoading = true

    await const index = store.table_timers.findIndex(({ order_id }) => order_id === tmp_order_id)

    await if (index != -1) {
        // Stop timer
        await clearInterval(store.table_timers[index].interval)

        // Remove timer
        await store.table_timers.splice(
            store.table_timers.findIndex(({ order_id }) => order_id === tmp_order_id), 1
        )

        await deliveryTime   = store.table_timers[index].time
    }

    try {

        await OrderHistory.updateColor({
            order_id: order_id,
            table_id: table_id,
            action: 'FOOD_DELIVERED',
        })

        // Save delivery time
        await OrderHistory.saveDeliveryTime({
            deliveryTime:   deliveryTime,
            order_id:       order_id,
        })

        // Refresh
        await OrderHistoryClass.getTotalOrderHistory({
            date: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        })

        let tables = await Data.getTables()
        await store.tables = tables.data

        await this.drawerOpened = false
    }

    await this.btnDeliveredLoading = false
},
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: You should only `await` things that are `async` (or are/return a `Promise`). Is the out of order *in* this function or *outside* this function (i.e. you need to `await` the call of this to make sure everything has completed here if you have code that depends on this being done).

Comment: What exactly is happening "out of order"? Did you make sure that all the asynchronous functions you are calling return a promise that doesn't fulfill before they are finished?

Comment: *"some things seem to execute before other things"*: please provide a reproducible example. As it is now, you have many function calls that are unknown to us, so there is no way we can see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use await only in a statement which is expected to return a `Promise` symbolising, that wait until the promise is returned. So, no not in every instruction, but in places where you require it.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I know if a statement returns a promise?

Comment: @Liga: How can you *not* know what value a function returns? When you call a function you should generally know what input it expects and what output it provides. Otherwise how can you be sure to call it correctly?

Comment: @Liga An arbitrary statement/expressions does in general *not* return a promise, like all those assignments in your code. The only thing that could return promises are function calls.

Comment: Thanks, this made sense to me to put await before only those statements that returns a promise. I found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely what you think is wrong.You only need to add `await` before async functions,not every statement.

```
async function logAsync(a) {
    return Promise.resolve(a);
}

function logSync(a) {
    console.log(a);
}

function combination() {
    // you only add await before async functions
    await logAsync("async 1");
    // this does not need await before
    logSync(1);
    logSync(2);
    logSync(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap whole block in try catch, and put await before statements that return Promises